# App not showing in TestFlight as App Store Connect User

Tags: ios, testflight, app-store-connect

I've submitted a build for my app on App Store Connect.

Under iOS Builds in the Testflight tab, the builds shows as "testing" for App Store Connect users, but App Store Connect Users page under "Testers & Groups", my info is there, but it says "No Builds Available"

Why the mismatch between the Builds page and the App Store Connect Users page? How do I get an invite/how do I get this build on my phone?

(the build is waiting for review for external testers)

Comment: Same problem, can you solve this?

Comment: The same problem for me. What is the reason?

Comment: Same problem but apparently no solution...